# espresso > how to select an option value in webview?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

in webview ,

i got two dropdownlist element with same option value

at first dropdownlist, i could select an option value by

```
onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//option[@value='01']"))
            .perform(webClick());
```

then, the result also action in first dropdownliast while i paste the same code

i though XPATH is search form head, so second dropdownlist  won't work

anyone could help me how to select option value in second dropdownlist?

Comment: is problem solved?

Comment: i think i slove by myself, i add second parameter to check value, show as below     onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
                .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//dd[@class='visitorBirth']//option[@value='01']"))
                .perform(webClick());

Comment: @HunterChen pls, post this comment as an answer (and mark it as chosen), so other people can see it better.

Comment: @ Willi Mentzel   thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update my answer as below

i think i slove by myself, i add second parameter to check value, show as below

```
onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//dd[@class='visitorBirth']//option[@value='01']"))
    .perform(webClick());
```